# Dataset to Excel - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I guess this question is already out in the internet a lot. I have gone through many of them but still stuck with this problem
My requirement is to get one of the Dataset Tables to a Excel file. I have all the data I need in a Dataset.Table object. Lot of the code on the internet talks about looping through the columns and rows and assigning it to the cell in Excel file. I am able to do that but that really doesnt solve the purpose as large datasets wiht a few thousand rows takes more than 5 minutes to execute and get an output.
Is there any other efficient way to do it? Any input is appreciated as every bit of information is useful to me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is free, very fast and very powerful Excel tool for visual studio using the and can do everything you want - They have the functionality to output a datatable directly to Excel using the `LoadFromDataTable()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your input! worked like a charm. And the library is great :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CSV file, and then open it with excel and convert within excel.

Comment: I have additional code that formats the excel file and my clients would prefer getting an excel output and work with it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly you want to do an excel file from a "dataset". You can try using CSV (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values); the format for CSV is really simple. For performance, store as much as data in the memory and finally write to a file, otherwise if you are writing to a file everytime you are reading a row from a dataset, then it will take much longer. Make sure your file ends with the extension of .csv otherwise MS excel will not open it. Hopefully this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am not sure if this can be done but my clients want some kind of color coding and formatting to be done on the file they get from my code. Can I do that with a csv file? I am sure I can do it on Excel and I have my code written for that. Can the same be done to a CSV file?

Comment: I don't think so. But I am not an expert in MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use GemBox Spreadsheet library (http://gemboxsoftware.com/). It does what you need.
They also have a free version.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I would prefer writing my own code than buy it. I did go to their website and have a look at their products and they do have some good stuff that I can use. Thanks for the ref